# Thread local attribute defined globally not accessible in threads

Tags: python, django, python-multithreading

```
import threading


threadlocal = threading.local()
threadlocal.depth = 0


def _increase_depth():
    threadlocal.depth += 1


def _decrease_depth():
    threadlocal.depth -= 1


def _use_it():
    print(threadlocal.depth)
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'depth'
```

What I would expect: each threads gets a `depth` initialized to `0`, and modifications will only visible within that particular thread.

Why are the attributes defined in `threadlocal` not accessible in the threads?

(This code is running in development with the django test server: I have not yet adapted it to produce a mimimum example which can be demonstrated with plain threads)

Comment: These are just function definitions, where exactly you are creating threads?

Comment: @TejasSarade as mentioned, that is done at the framework level. This is not a full, testable example

Answer (score 1):

> What I would expect: each threads gets a `depth` initialized to `0`

That's not how it works. Only the thread that created your global `threadlocal` variable set `depth` to `0`. Presumably the main thread. You have to initialize the value in each thread separately.

Comment: How would I go about this? I do not get notified in any way that a new thread has been created. The only thing I *could* do, and it's ugly, is to test if the attribute already exists, and initialize it if it does not. But that means: 1) using my attributes need to include information on how to *initialize* the attributes. Ugly! 2) The global attribute declaration serves absolutely no purpose. I can simply throw it to the bin. What a weird implementation.

Comment: So, for my understanding: each thread, gets a `threadlocal` variable (with each thread getting a different copy). That variable is global in each thread (functions and methods can access it). And the main thread (only the main thread) initializes the `threadlocal` variale. I assume that is a side effect of how the interpreter loads the code and creates the main thread during parse time. It still very weird: main thread and the rest of the threads behave very differently.

Comment: @dangonfast `threadlocal` is a global object. It is initialized only once and all threads share it. But `.depth` is not a simple "get/set `depth` attribute". It is overwritten by Python and actually the threadlocal data is accessed during this attribute operation. That's why it is initialized only for the main thread. You can think of `threadlocal` object as a namespace for thread local data.

Comment: My advice is simple: do not use thread locals. Whatever you are trying to do, most likely can be done in a different, more sane way. I don't want to even think about horrors of debugging code with thread local data.

Comment: My original implementation only uses globals, but fails. The problem: I want to trace calls with a decorator, and have a global `depth` variable to keep track of the depth of the call stack (for indentation purposes). The webapp is serving parallel requests and the depth global variable is increased/decreased by the different threads, causing confussion. I see no way of solving the problem but by limiting the deph variable to the context where the API requests are being processed, which is a thread.

Comment: You could wrap `threadlocal` with a getter and setter functions/objects and utilize `hasattr` inside them. Then in your decorators you simply do `get_current_depth()` and `add_to_current_depth(1)`, `add_to_current_depth(-1)`. As a side note: I'm not sure why you want to trace calls with a decorator, but I advice against it.

Comment: What I know is that thread local variable has to be declared inside function. If you declare it outside the function, it will be thread local but for the 'main thread' or whatever is controlling threads in your program.

Comment: @freakish yes, that's what I had in mind. I have added the implementation in a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

This implementation solves my problems:

```
import threading

_INDENT = '   '

_threadlocal = threading.local()
_defaults = dict(depth=0, prefix='')


class ThreadLocal:

    _initialized = False  # This allows us to set / get attributes during __init__

    def __init__(self, thread_data, defaults=None):
        self._thread_data = thread_data
        self._defaults = defaults or {}
        self._initialized = True

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if self._initialized:
            setattr(self._thread_data, key, value)
        else:
            # Allow setting attributes in __init__
            self.__dict__[key] = value

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if self._initialized:
            return getattr(self._thread_data, item, _defaults.get(item))
        else:
            # Allow getting attributes in __init__
            return self.__dict__[item]


threadlocal = ThreadLocal(_threadlocal, _defaults)


def _increase_depth():
    threadlocal.depth += 1
    threadlocal.prefix = _INDENT * threadlocal.depth


def _decrease_depth():
    threadlocal.depth -= 1
    threadlocal.prefix = _INDENT * threadlocal.depth
```